# Unknown type name 'count' at c

Tags: c, debugging, multidimensional-array, error-handling, nested

i want to compare all the strings in the array string[1000][1000] with more than 10 letters in the string. so here in my code i use a nested loop to try and compare it to the other strings in the array. but it said that the code give this error to me "unknown type name 'count'", "   [Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant"  and "[Error] expected identifier or '(' before '}' token"
why is this keep happening?

```
void main() 
{
char string[1000][1000];
int i, o = 1, sentence;

printf("enter the number of speeches: ");
scanf("%d", &sentence);

for (i = 0; i < sentence; i++)
{
    printf("\nplease enter speech number %d: ", o);
    scanf("%s", &string[i]);
    o++;
}


int q, w, t, count = 0;

for(q = 0; q < sentence; q++)
{
    t = strlen(string[q]);
    if (t >= 10)
    {
        if (q = 0)
        {
        count++;
        }
        
        else 
        {
            for(w = 0; w < q; w++)
            {
                if (strcmp(string[q], string[w]) == 0)
                {
                    count += 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    count++;
            }
        }               
        }
    }
}
printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: On of those two `}` with the same indentation is probably wrong.

Comment: Unrelated: `scanf("%s", string[i]);` (with no `&`) and `if (q == 0)` (with comparison rather than assignment)

Comment: `count += 0;` doesn't to anything useful, you don't need it.

Comment: Also your array `string` takes  almost a whole MiB of memory, which puts it very close to the stack limit on Windows (which only gives each process a single MiB stack by default). Use pointers and dynamic allocation, or possibly variable-length arrays after you have read the value of `sentence`.

Comment: Or just make `string` a global variable.

Comment: Two obvious problem:  (1) You duplicated a line with a `}`, so the the final `printf` call is actually outside the function, and (2) `if (q = 0)` should presumably be `if (q == 0)`

Comment: sorry im still really new at programming so im clueless about a lot of stuff

Comment: Consistent code style really helps. That includes indentation, and if you're going to use curly braces on `if`, use them on the corresponding `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 mistakes.

```
for(q = 0; q < sentence; q++)
{
    t = strlen(string[q]);
    if (t >= 10)
    {
        if (q == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
        
        else 
        {
            for(w = 0; w < q; w++)
            {
                if (strcmp(string[q], string[w]) == 0)
                {
                    count += 0;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    count++;
                }
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: You forgot to remove the useless `count += 0;` assignment.